# Binding Value of function before showing new page angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to bind a variable to a scope before it moves to the view but my view shows before the variable is bounded. Here is my code.

```
$scope.getListing = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      $rootScope.listingDetails =[];
      referralCasesGroupByCaseStatus.getListing($rootScope.userDetails.rows.item(2).value).then(function(data){
        $rootScope.listingDetails = data
        deferred.resolve($rootScope.listingDetails)

          if($rootScope.fromDashboard === false) {
            $scope.showCaseStatus(1); 
            $state.go('app.case_status')  
          }
          else {
            $scope.showCaseStatus($rootScope.statusNumber)
            $state.go('app.case_status')
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
      });
    }) 
    return deferred.promise; 
  };
  var changedNumber = 0;

  $scope.showCaseStatus = function(number) {
      var finishedPushingListings = false;
      $rootScope.listingByCaseStatus = [];
      $rootScope.caseStatusListings = [];

      if(changedNumber !== 0 && changedNumber !== number) {
        changedNumber = number;
      }
      else {
        if(changedNumber > 0) {
          $scope.$applyAsync($rootScope.detailsPresent = true);
        }
      }
      $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
        angular.forEach($rootScope.listingDetails, function(value, key) {
          if(value.real_estate_agent_assignment_status_id == number) {
            $rootScope.listingByCaseStatus.push(value);
          }
        });
      })

      $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
        if($rootScope.listingByCaseStatus == 0 || $rootScope.listingByCaseStatus == undefined || $rootScope.listingByCaseStatus == null) {  
          $rootScope.detailsPresent = true;  
          $rootScope.changeNumber = true; 
          finishedPushingListings = true;
        }  
        else {
          $rootScope.detailsPresent = false;
          $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false; 
          $rootScope.changeNumber = true;  
          finishedPushingListings = true;  
        }  
      }) 
  };
```

The main problem here is that the function `$scope.showCaseStatus($rootScope.statusNumber)` doesnt finish executing before it executes the `$state.go('app.case_status')` and i would like for it to wait and finish executing before it jumps to the `$state.go('app.case_status')`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look into [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve), it does exactly what you want

Comment: Is there a meaningful reason to use `$applyAsync` inside `showCaseStatus()`?

Comment: `$scope.$applyAsync($rootScope.detailsPresent = true);` javascript currently doesn't support lambda expressions. This works not the way you expect. This assignment is performed immediately and call to `$applyAsync` is useless

Comment: Once `showCaseStatus` becomes synchronous there shouldn't be any problem like described

Comment: @KirillSlatin the reason behind it was to just ensure that it was being executed before it jumps out of the else statement.

Comment: @KirillSlatin yes my problem now is that since showCaseStatus is not synchronous it doesnt finish executing before it executes $state.go('app.case_status')

Comment: `ensure that it was being executed before it jumps out` I don't clearly understand... `$applyAsync` leads to the fact that functions passed to it as parameters are executed AFTER the state is changed. So you using it instead of `$apply` led to the problem

Comment: $apply gives me an error that's why i didnt use it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `$applyAsync()`, the function effects are asynchronous. One way to achieve what you want is to make `showCaseStatus()` return a promise - and take into account that there are 2 asynchronous blocks:

```
$scope.showCaseStatus = function(number) {
    var ..., d1, d2;

    ...

    d1 = $q.defer();
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      angular.forEach($rootScope.listingDetails, function(value, key) {
        ...
      });
      d1.resolve();
    })

    d2 = $q.defer();
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      ...
      d2.resolve();
    })

    // both promises must be resolved to continue
    return $q.all([d1.promise, d2.promise]);
};
```

Then the caller becomes:

```
$scope.showCaseStatus($rootScope.statusNumber).then(function() {
    $state.go('app.case_status')
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

Some notes:

- If you do not need the async blocks, you can remove them and simplify the code
- If the second async block relies on the result of the first, they too should be synchronized